# python print something like warning or error (shown in red)

Tags: python, warnings, stdout

I've seen some libs print things via warning or error stream (e.g. tqdm), and the text is  shown in red.

So my question is: How to print arbitrary text like that? I plan to highlight some stdout info in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'This is a warning!')
```